# How would the following c(++)-struct be converted to C# for p/invoke usage

Tags: c#, struct, pinvoke

Im trying to wrap an older dll and am running into issues representing a structure it uses in C#. Nothing I have tried seems to be working. Any magicians able to help?

```
typedef struct _PARAM_BYNAME_DATA 
{ 
    n_char *szPntName; /* (in) point name */ 
    n_char *szPrmName; /* (in) parameter name */ 
    n_long nPrmOffset; /* (in) parameter offset */ 
    PARvalue *pupvValue; /* (in/out) parameter value union */ 
    n_ushort nType; /* (in/out) value type */ 
    n_long fStatus; /* (out) status of each value access */ 
} PARAM_BYNAME_DATA;
```

If it helps the below is a VB port.

```
Type param_byname_data 
    point_name As String
    param_name As String
    param_offset As Long
    padding1 As Long 'for byte alignment between VB and C 
     param_value As Variant
    param_type As Integer
    padding2 As Integer 'for byte alignment between VB and C 
    status As Long status As Long 
End Type
```

And the following Delphi as well...

```
PARAM_BYNAME_DATA=record
    PntName:pchar;       // (in) point name
    PrmName:pchar;       // (in) parameter name
    PrmOffset:longword;  // (in) parameter offset
    pValue:pointer;      // (out) parameter value union
    nType:word;          // (out) value type
    fStatus:longword;    // (out) status of each value access */
end;
```

Comment: Since we don't know what n_char, n_long, PARvalue, n_ushort and n_long are it's hard to help. Are n_*** and *** always equivalent? And please tell us what PARvalue is.

Comment: Ok... here I was thinking these are nice normal c types. My bad. I have VB alternative as well. have updated question. Unsure if the padding is required in C#?

Comment: so PARvalue is a Variant

Comment: Your Delphi version is wrong by the way. Instead of longword and word which are unsigned, you should use the signed equivalents integer and shortint. And why not use a Variant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The struct should look something like this...

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MyStruct
{
    public string point_name;
    public string param_name;
    public Int32 param_offset;
    public VariantWrapper param_value;
    public Int32 param_type;
    public Int32 status;
};
```

Here is a [good article](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84519/mastering-structs-in-c/) that talks about structs and alignment that should help.  The main thing is the struct layout and the bit alignment.  It has been a while since I have had to marshal values out of C++ but I hope this helps.

Comment: param_type should be UInt16 I believe. And don't you need to specify ANSI characters or is that done in the function call? Otherwise I think this is spot on and you beat me to it by a few minutes.

Comment: Yes.  And it is ANSI by default (but not in VB.NET).  The equivalent of a Variant is *object*.